# Failed to set a breakpoint in Java abstract class

Tags: android, android-studio, debugging

I am learning PKMS by debugging it in Android Studio. But I failed to set breakpoint at method handleStartCopy(), or say it in another way, it didn't stop at the breakpoint I set.

Comment: After I did some comparation, I found I it only failed when I tried to set breakpoint at an abstract class method

Comment: I clear all the files that Android Studio produced, and re-import AOSP, it works again.

Answer (score -1):

Set the breakpoint in the class where this method is implemented. That's what will actually be executed when the code is run.

Answer (score -1):

You cannot put breakpoints in the abstract classes because they do not have any implementation to watch over.

If you want to put breakpoint for that method, search the class where you have implemented it and search for the method annotated with `@override`.

inside that class, your breakpoints will work perfectly.

Comment: class PackageHandler extends Handler {
        ...

        private boolean connectToService() {
            Intent service = new Intent().setComponent(DEFAULT_CONTAINER_COMPONENT);
            ....
        }
}

Comment: this should be the implement of abstract class, but, yeah, didn't work